# Proving $3^n>n^4$, for all $n\geq 8$

Tags: induction

> Prove $3^n>n^4$, for all $n\geq 8$.

I solved this for 4 - 5 hours now, but I still don't get any ideas other than plugging in $n$. Please give me some hints. Any hints are fine. Please use induction!

Comment: Can you compare the size of $3^{n+1}/3^{n}$ with $(n+1)^4/n^4$?

Comment: Let's start with the base case. Have you verified that $3^8 > 8^4$?

Answer (score 2):

We have $3^8 \geqslant 8^{4}$.

Let's suppose the property is true for some $n\geqslant 8$.
Then $3^{n+1} \geqslant 3.n^4$, and $(n+1)^4 = n^4 + 4n^3 + 6n^2 + 4n +1$.

So we want to prove that $2n^4-4n^3-6n^2-4n-1\geqslant 0$. By dividing by $n^2$, we have to prove that $2n^2 \geqslant 4n + 6 +4/n +1/n^2$, or just $2n^2 \geqslant 4n + 12$, which is equivalent to $n^2 \geqslant 2n + 6$. And since $n^2 - 2n - 6 = (n-4)(n+2)$ is $\geqslant 0$ for $n\geqslant 8$.

This gives the answer.

---

Note that you can also do without induction by directly deriving $f:x\mapsto 3^x - x^4$ $4$ times.

Comment: It would simplify a bit to divide with n^2 so you only have to prove that $ 3n^2 \geqslant n^2 + 4n + 6 + 4/n + 1/n^2 $ or just $ 3n^2 \geqslant n^2 + 4n + 16 $ which is equivalent to $ (n-4)(n+2) \geqslant 0$ (simplify = without derivatives)

Comment: Brillant! I edited.